# Temporarily creating an ImageView - Multi-Touch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multi-touch

PREFACE: i am very new to swift and ios Dev. Please be kind.

I want to create a image highlighting the area on which the user touched.

So far I have this:

```
// Dictionary that holds my image view per touch
var allImgViews : [Int : UIImageView] = [:]

 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    var image = UIImage(named: "dot.png");
    var imgView = UIImageView(image: image);


    for fing : AnyObject in touches
    {
        let loc = fing.locationInView(self.view);

        imgView.frame = CGRect(x: loc.x, y: loc.y, width: 100, height: 100);
        self.view.addSubview(imgView);

        // ----- PROBLEM -------
        // need to find a way to store the touched point imgView ...
        // such that when touchsEnded is reached, only the point ended will
        // vanish. This will also allow for multitouching.

    }

}
```

From here I have the touchesEnded method which (in theory) will get the correct imgView with a key, and perform the removeFromSuperview() method, thus deleting the icon when the user lifts their finger. I am having trouble trying to find a good key to use to solve this problem. And I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about handling multi-touches.

Thanks.

Comment: imgview only exists in your touchesbegan method.  in order to keep track of it you need to declare it as a property of the class youre working with.  then you can add and remove it from anywhere in your class.

Comment: well if i make it global, how will i create multiple and delete only the ones that have been untouched.

Comment: Don't totally understand what you're trying to do

Comment: @hamobi I am trying to create an image as the user touches the screen. If the user releases their finger, the image should be deleted and not show up.

Comment: Then using a the imgview as a property should do what youre asking for.  you touch the screen.  just addSubview, when you release your finger, removeFromSuperview.  Thats all there is to it.